# Custom Post Type active link - Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a custom post type named 'schools' on my wordpress site. When you hover over the schools tab a list of schools are shown in the submenu. These are pages I created with different school names. Now when you click on one of the school pages I have a sidebar with all the schools so they can naviate through the different schools from the sidebar rather than using the menu.

I have the sidebar being populated using the following snippet.

```
while( $shools_loop->have_posts() ) : $schools_loop->the_post();

  $content .= '<li class="schools-list">';
  $content .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
  $content .= '</li>';

endwhile;
```

This works perfectly and I can navigate through all the schools without a problem from my sidebar. I'm trying to find a way to when I view a school via the sidebar or nav that when I'm on the active page I create some css styling to the li of the ACTIVE page. I've already figured out how to do this with the nav menu. But need help on the sidebar menu. Since the sidebar list menu is being populated I'm unsure how to check if the custom post type link is active and corresponds to the /schools/get-title page.

I found something like this online and I've tried editing it, but I'm not sure if this only works for nav menu

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'services',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Services' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Services' )
      ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'services'),
    )
  );
}

// highlight active custom post page in nav
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'namespace_menu_classes', 10, 2 );
function namespace_menu_classes( $classes , $item ){
  if ( get_post_type() == 'services' ) {
    // remove unwanted classes if found
    $classes = str_replace( 'current_page_parent', '', $classes );
    // find the url you want and add the class you want
    if ( $item->url == 'services/physical-therapy-services/' ) {
      $classes = str_replace( 'menu-item', 'menu-item current_page_parent', $classes );
    }
  }
  return $classes;
  }
```

Basically need to find a way to check whether the custom post type is active or not.

Comment: The "services" should read "schools"

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `global` variable in the main template page with the ID of the current post and then in your sidebar loop, you can retrieve that `global` variable and compare it with current post's ID by using `get_the_ID()` function and then perform the necessary actions.

Example:

**single-cpt.php**

```
// Inside the loop
global $post_id = get_the_ID();
```

**sidebar-cpt.php**

```
$post_id = isset($_GLOBALS['post_id']) ? $_GLOBALS['post_id'] : 0;
while( $shools_loop->have_posts() ) : $schools_loop->the_post();
  if($post_id == get_the_ID()){
      // This is the active link
      $content .= '<li class="schools-list selected">';

  } else {
      $content .= '<li class="schools-list">';

  }

  $content .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
  $content .= '</li>';

endwhile;
```

Comment: can you show me a rough example on how to do this please?